# Anything behind 'if __name__ == "__main__":' not executing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

So, here's my situation.

I'm using PyDev in Eclipse, Python interpreter version 2.7.2 in Windows.

I'm using the built in multiprocessing library in an attempt to fork off a bunch of processes to parallelize a very compute-intensive loop.  The tutorials I've looked at say to use,

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

to prevent it from spawning off near-infinite processes and bringing my system to its knees, essentially.

The problem is, I am calling this from a module, not my main script; as such, nothing after it EVER gets executed.  No chance for parallelism at all.  Of course, if I remove it, I get the infiniprocess spam that kills the machine executing the code.

For reference's sake, here's the relevant code:

```
from tribe import DataCache
from tribe import WorldThread
from tribe import Actor
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing

class World:
def __init__(self,numThreads,numActors,tickRate):
    print "Initalizing world..."
    self.cache = DataCache.DataCache()
    self.numThreads = numThreads
    self.numActors = numActors
    self.tickRate = tickRate
    self.actors = []
    self.processes = []
    for i in range(numActors):
        self.actors.append(Actor.Actor("test.xml",self.cache))
    print "Actors loaded."
def start_world(self):
    print "Starting world"
    run_world = True;
    while run_world:
        self.world_tick()
        sleep(2)

def world_tick(self):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            print "World tick"
            actor_chunk = len(self.actors)/self.numThreads
            if len(self.processes)==0:
                for _ in range(self.numThreads):
                    new_process = multiprocessing.Process(WorldThread.WorldProcess.work, args=(_, self.actors[_*actor_chunk,(_+1)*actor_chunk]))
```

And the class it is calling:

```
class WorldProcess():
def __init__(self):
    print "World process initilized."
    ''' Really, I'm not sure what kind of setup we'll be doing here yet. '''
def work(self, process_number, actors):
    print "World process" + str(process_number) + " running."
    for actor in actors:
        actor.tick()
    print "World process" + str(process_number) + " completed."
```

Am I correct in my assessment that the whole if **name** == "main": check only works if you have it in the executable script itself?  If so, how do you safely fork off processes from within modules?  If not, why isn't it working here?

Comment: The call `multiprocessing.Process(WorldThread.WorldProcess.work, …)` looks suspect. You're calling an instance method of a class, but I don't think the multiprocessing module will instantiate it for you. You're also not calling the method with keyword arguments like the documentation indicates – the first argument to `Process` is a deprecated one that should always be omitted.

Comment: Whoops, I definitely made one mistake in there -- I should have put in target=WorldThread.WorldProcess...etc  Furthermore, all of the examples I've seen (and admittedly they're limited) have called on methods from imported classes without instantiating those classes, so I doubt that's the issue.  The real issue I'm having, though, is the fact that nothing behind the name == main check not executing.  What I really wanted was a clarification on that point, and how one safely multiprocesses from within modules.

Comment: `if __name__=="__main__"` is something you do at the root level of a script that is going to be an entry point. Its a way to only do things if the script is being executed directly.

Comment: I actually dont see why you would have an issue with infinite processes be spawned. If you have a script that is the entry point, you do the name == main. And in a module you want to multiprocess, you just loop and start your processes the same way you loop and start threads

Comment: jdi -- I thought it was something like that.  That begs the question, though; what does one do to safely fork off a process from within a module?

Comment: Are you actually having this problem or trying to preemptively solve it? If you just loop 4 times and start processes on a method as a target it should work.

Comment: Okay, jdi, based on your second comment, I think I misunderstood your first.  You're saying that I put the name==main check in the script's entry point even if my fork happens in the module, correct? Anyway, I tried that, and it appeared to resolve the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: I actually did have the infinite loop problem, and did have a problem with it blocking on the name==main check; I didn't include my entry point because I didn't think it was relevant.  Now I know better.  Thanks again.

Comment: I moved those comments to an answer.

Comment: Please fix the question title to use `==` instead of `=`.  When the title is wrong like that, it devalues the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this as an answer, since it was in the comments:

`if __name__ == "__main__"` is something you do at the root level of a script that is going to be an entry point. Its a way to only do things if the script is being executed directly.

If you have a script that is the entry point, you do the name == main. And in a module you want to multiprocess, you just loop and start your processes the same way you loop and start threads.

Answer (score 2):

To control the amount of processes, use the `Pool` class from `multiprocessing`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(5)
def f(x):
     return x*x
p.map(f, [1,2,3])
```

(Edit: as per comment, this is just **howto** for the Pool class.  [see](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction) more)

Using `__name__` is not required, since you explicitly pass `Process` the **actual python function** to run.

This:

```
def world_tick(self):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print "World tick"
        actor_chunk = len(self.actors)/self.numThreads
        if len(self.processes)==0:
            for _ in range(self.numThreads):
                new_process = multiprocessing.Process(WorldThread.WorldProcess.work, args=(_, self.actors[_*actor_chunk,(_+1)*actor_chunk]))
```

is very bad. Simplify it.

A better pattern will be:

```
class WorkArgs(object):
    ... many attributes follow ...

def proc_work(world_thread, work_args):
    world_thread.WorldProcess.work(work_args.a, work_args.b, ... etc)

p = Pool(5)
p.map(proc_work, [(world_thread, args0), (world_thread, args1), ...])
```

Hope this helps!

As a side note, pickling your arguments and passing them to other processes will result in **importing** your module. So, it is best to make sure you module doesn't preform any forking/magic/work unless it is told so (e.g, only has function/class definitions or `__name__` magic, not actual code blocks).

Comment: Your first example crashes with `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'`

Comment: Ah, I like it.  Examining your code, it looks like the p.map is what actually executes what you've set up above, the equivalent of the call to instantiate multiprocessing.process in my code  (albeit much nicer), wherein you put in the function to call, and then just pass a list of tuples each containing an instance of WorldThread to use and the arguments to be used.  Is my assessment correct?